# No package rrdtool-perl available

Tags: centos, centos5, rrdtool

On a CentOS release 5.10 (Final) I am trying to install `rrdtool` to get RRDs.pm but I have no luck.

```
yum install rrdtool-perl
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * rpmforge: mirror.team-cymru.org
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
No package rrdtool-perl available.
Nothing to do
```

I tried also `librrds-perl` but that was not found either.

**2. I tried:**

```
yum whatprovides "*/RRDs.pm"
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * rpmforge: mirror.team-cymru.org
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
cpanel-perl-514-Log-Log4perl-1.37-1.cp1136.x86_64 : CPAN module - Log4j implementation for Perl
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/514/lib64/perl5/cpanel_lib/Log/Log4perl/Appender/RRDs.pm



cpanel-perl-514-RRDs-v1.4.7-1.cp1136.x86_64 : CPAN module - unknown
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/514/lib64/perl5/cpanel_lib/x86_64-linux-64int/RRDs.pm
```

then I tried installing but I got: No package cpanel-perl available and the variants (tried with full name, tried both repos listed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On CentOS 5, this is not in the default Repo, but in e.g. [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).